# how to drop a primary key in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to drop a primary key with t-sql(i mean script)
like alter table tablename modify primary key..!
how to write a script to drop a primary key?
thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To `Drop` any `constraint` this is the method

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtable -- Table Name
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_primarykey_name -- Primary Key name
```

If you don't know the primary key `constraint` name then run the below script to know

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME  
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable'  -- Table Name
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'  -- change it if table is in some other schema 
       AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Comment: i got an error msg

Comment: like this-- 
Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'id' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: @SunilThoutam - So it is not your constraint name. Run my second query and add proper constraint name

Comment: thanq its done..!

Comment: create TABLE Persons1
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID1 PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName,firstname)
)

Comment: @SunilThoutam `pk_PersonID1` is the primary key constraint name

Comment: when i execute.. in design it is showing two primary keys..what it exactly means thanks in advance

Comment: primary key constraint name is "PK__tblperso__3213E83F03317E3D"

Comment: can you tell me above table what is primary key in that which has two fields?

Comment: @SunilThoutam - A table can have only one primary key. It is not possible did you add this filter `CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'`

Comment: actually it is created that why i am confused.!